Is there a definition of "energy type"?
I see things like "Epic Spell Seed: Ward" mention the energy types including Acid, Cold, Electricity, Fire, and Sonic.
But things like "Mastery of Element" does not specify a limitation on energy types.
In some discussions, some claims that "force" is an energy type. But all force effects are simply doing damage without specifying the type to be "force damage", so it feels weird to convert a typed damage to an untyped damage with the effect.
I am wondering if there's an official definition of "energy type" somewhere so that I can learn what counts as "energy type" and what cannot.
For now, I am assuming that "anything that can be listed in 'resist' section of the monster entry can be a valid energy type". That comes to the 5 elemental energy types mentioned above, and positive and negative energy that appears on certain extensions like Elder Evil (an Archmage converts fireball to positive energy to heal his allies feels strange (but somehow reasonable), though). Plain (untyped) energies like half of the damage in Flame Strike doesn't count, I suppose.
Or should I just house rule it? I guess that would be the last resort so I am avoiding that. But feel free to share some popular house rules around this matter.

Sort of, but it’s not really useful:
There are definitions—which have some issues of their own—but most effects don’t use them, and instead define exactly what damage types they work with. A specific list within an effect overrides any general list, so most of the time, the general definition isn’t in play.
Anyway, the original, core definitions are found in the glossary, which is sort of problematic because the glossary entries are usually abbreviated treatments of concepts with fuller details in the rules—which sometimes add important caveats, qualifications, and the like. For this, there are no fuller details anywhere else, and we have just the glossary definitions.
And then this goes from “sort of problematic” to really problematic by having two definitions contradict one another:

damage: […] Damage types include […] energy damage (positive, negative, acid, cold, electricity, fire, and sonic).

(Player’s Handbook Glossary, pg. 307)

energy damage: Damage caused by one of five types of energy (not counting positive and negative energy): acid, cold, electricity, fire, and sonic.

(Player’s Handbook Glossary, pg. 308)
Rules Compendium pulls these definitions out of the glossary and gives them more “primary” treatment, and nixes the mention of positive and negative energy, which is probably for the best overall. But then Rules Compendium has its own problems.

Damage Types
[…]
Energy
Abilities and effects that employ one of the five energy types deal energy damage, which can be acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic.

(Rules Compendium, pg. 42)

Energy
Some effects use or create energy, dealing damage according to the type of energy used. Energy comes in five types: acid, cold, electricity, fire, and sonic.

(Rules Compendium, pg. 48)
And at the end of the day, this kinda-sorta winds up not mattering much because most effects define exactly which types they work with—see resist energy, protection from energy, Energy Substitution, the energy ray et al. series of psionic powers, etc. Cases like the archmage’s mastery of energy that don’t specify what they mean by “energy” are rare—and probably mistakes.
But, if all else fails, it is both reasonable and probably fair to fall back on the acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic definition. All else equal, sonic is usually the best as it is resisted far, far less often than the other types, though obviously if you know of a particular weakness you’ll prefer that.
As for “force damage,” that... is its own mess. It seems that “force damage,” rather than being a damage type the way “fire damage” is, is instead shorthand for “damage from a force effect.”

force damage: A special type of damage dealt by force effects, such as a magic missile spell. A force effect can strike incorporeal creatures without the normal miss chance associated with incorporeality.

(Player’s Handbook Glossary, pg. 308-309)
(Also, notably missing from both the “damage” and “energy damage” entries.)
In this sense, you are correct to say that it’s untyped damage... but it’s certainly very weird. Magic missile et al. definitely say they do “XdY force damage” in their descriptions. Also, if this is correct, they don’t have to—if a force effect said just “damage,” or even “fire damage,” that damage would still “be” force damage and ignore incorporeality.

One thing might worth mentioning: Force Dragon's "Immune to Force" ability says "A force dragon cannot be harmed by any force effect". Apparently "force effect" is a special term and doesn't sound like an energy or element.

@TerryWindwalker Well, “{descriptor} effect” is a well-defined concept in the rules; that wording is used consistently to mean an effect with that descriptor. But yes, unlike fire damage or bludgeoning damage or whatever, “force damage” is not a description of the damage itself, but rather a description of the effect that deals the damage. Hence the possibility of a force effect that deals fire damage—it still is force damage, in addition to being fire damage. (The bigger question on the force dragon is what exactly “harm” means in this context.)
